# Inserting random div class into id

Tags: jquery

Previously I have used Math.random() to load, say, a random image into a div. I want to use this again but I am no jQuery expert I don't know if this is possible. I have some div IDs positioned absolutely, and some classes (.content) I want to randomnly select and load into those IDs. So:

```
<div id="veh1" class="abs"></div>
<div id="veh2" class="abs"></div>

.abs { position: absolute }

<div class="content">ONE</div>
<div class="content">TWO</div>
<div class="content">THREE</div>
<div class="content">FOUR</div>

.content { display: none }
```

To end up with

```
<div id="veh1" class="abs"><div class="content" style="display: block">TWO</div></div>
<div id="veh2" class="abs"><div class="content" style="display: block">FOUR</div></div>
```

I know I could do something like this with the relevant Math.random() and .show() script.

```
<div id="veh1" class="abs">
<div class="content" style="display:block">ONE</div>
<div class="content" style="display:none">TWO</div>
<div class="content" style="display:none">THREE</div>
<div class="content" style="display:none">FOUR</div>
</div>
```

I could do that for each ID and load within various predetermined contents , though it kind of defies the point of it being entirely random and I doubt that would be the best way of doing this. I have searched around but found no examples of how it could be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
var count = $('.content').length,
    rnd = Math.round(Math.random()*count);
    $randomDiv = $('.content').eq(rnd);

$randomDiv.css({ color: 'red' }); //do stuff with the randomly selected div
```

This would result in something like this:

```
$('div.abs').each(function(i, el){
     //do the random stuff in here
     $(el).append($randomDiv);
});
```

Don't forget to check if a certain `.content` div has been inserted already (I just assume you don't want that).

http://jsfiddle.net/PnRYc/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. But I'd like to try to achieve a randomly selected .content to be loaded into a randomly selected div id of #veh1, #veh2, #veh3 (which could also have class of .abs) and so on. There could be 10 div IDs and 50 .contents, with ten inserted into the IDs and the rest hidden. Does that seem to make sense? At the moment I could only think to use either of yours or Patryk's answers to randomly load only certain contents in certain IDs.

Comment: Well, it's hard to say if it makes sense, since I don't know what you're trying to achieve. But I have showed you some simple randomization. Then it's up to you if you want to move/hide/show/clone the elements. I think you should be able to figure it out. If not, let me know

Comment: Sure I am going to manage with this, with a simpler approach than original. Patryk's code also works but I can't answer both or even up vote. So I'll mark this one as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is better

```
$('.abs').each(function () {
    var el = $('div.content').eq(Math.round(Math.random() * $('div.content').length))
    $(this).append(el)
    el.remove();
});
```

Comment: Cheers for suggestion, this does as intended. Sometimes though on page refresh it returns a blank div. It seems to be better in this case to just do this var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.selector').length); $('.selector').eq(rand).show(); with css as .selector display: none